# Number of integer side triangles having the same circumcenter.

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I proposed in a Spanish mathematics magazine (in 2008) the following geometry problem with its solution: how many integer side triangles $a\le b\le c$ can be formed for an integer $c\gt 2 $?. 
Reviewing this problem, I can think of another one that I propose here and that is somewhat more difficult (or, to taste, less easy):

Let be a triangle with integer sides $a\le b\le c$ with  $a,b,c$ coprimes and its circumscribed circle $\Gamma$. How many triangles with integer sides can be inscribed in $\Gamma$ such that one of its sides coincides with one of the sides of the given triangle?

I am particularly interested that there is none other than the same triangle given. I am aware that the problem could be perhaps very difficult to fully answer.

Comment: The wording here is a little unclear. Is it enough for the integer-sided triangles to have the same circumcircle, or is it necessary for them to share a side or something?

Comment: Integer-sided  triangles inscribed in $\Gamma$ and sharing a side of the fixed triangle $\triangle{ABC}$